# How to render optgroup in WTForms in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I want to render HTML like this in Flask-WTF and WTForms.

```html
<select name="animal-box">
<optgroup label="mammal">
  <option label="cat" value="cat">cat</option>
  <option label="dog" value="dog">dog</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label=reptile">
  <option label="turtle" value="turtle">turtle</option>
  <option label="lizard" value="lizard">lizard</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

How can I define a form to render HTML above?

#### forms.py

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import  SelectMultipleField
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    # How can I define optgroup here?
    animal =  SelectMultipleField('animal', choices=[('cat', 'cat'), ('dog', 'dog'), ('turtle', 'turtle'), ('lizard', 'lizard')])
```

I have searched around the document but suppose it is not possible to do that by WTForms. So is that any workaround to accomplish this?

Comment: [wtforms-components](https://github.com/kvesteri/wtforms-components) has support for selects with option groups.

Comment: look at the documentation for custom widgets

Answer (score 2):

Since [version 3](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#version-300), you can have optgroups using a dict in the `choices` argument:

```
Class MyForm():
    animal = SelectMultipleField(                                                                                                  
        'animal',                                                                                                                  
        choices = {                                                                                                                
            'feline': [(3, 'cat'), (5, 'lion')],                                                                                   
            'canis': [(4, 'dog')],                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                          
    )
```